# How to activate Fitness and Fitness+ on Watch 6 and iPhone 11?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, fitness+

I see this when I open Fitness on the iPhone:

[image: first set up Activity on your Apple Watch]

> Fitness
> The Fitness app works with your Apple Watch to keep track of your activity and workout history. To start using the app on your iPhone, first set up Activity on your Apple Watch.

I see this when I open fitness on watch 6:

[image: To start sharing your Activity, use the Fitness app on your iPhone.]

> Sharing
> To start sharing your Activity, use the Fitness app on your iPhone.

There is nothing to advance.

I have restarted both devices and the problem persists.

watch 6 is on watchOS 8.1 and the iPhone on iOS 15.1.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you launch the Fitness app on your iPhone, as instructed?

Comment: yes, the first screenshot is the fitness running in the iPhone.

Comment: Do you live in a region where Fitness+ is available ?? - From November 3. it would be USA and then the 15 new countries Austria, Brazil, Colombia, France, Germany, Indonesia, Italy, Malaysia, Mexico, Portugal, Russia, Saudi Arabia, Spain, Switzerland

Comment: Yes, Portugal...

Comment: I asked my question the wrong way, sorry.  On your Watch, you're showing the 2nd of 3 screens (you're on Activity Sharing).  When you swipe that screen from right to left, do you see the Activity screen?

Comment: yes, left I see the activity screen and right the awards.

Comment: The screen you are seeing on your watch is a secondary feature, fitness sharing. In this case, your watch is set up but your phone doesn't see that.

Comment: I have not the faintest idea how to solve that.

Comment: @Duck Glad you figured it out - I didn't know either, just wanted to help clarify 

Comment: Thanks @Ezekiel. It was the only thing I have not tried yet. 

Answer (score 1):

I unpaired both and paired them again. It is now working.

Thanks everybody commenting.